# Fantastic edit by Community user. Did it really do this?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edits, community-user

I was looking at an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12270782/revisions) and saw it had been edited by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). The edit was pretty substantial and quite good. Was this really done by a bot? Am I not understanding what Community does? This kind of edit seems beyond the m.o. of it's about section.

[image]

Comment: Community takes ownership of edits contributed by anonymous users. So no, it wasn't a bot who did that.

Comment: Let's not be so hasty to discount the bot theory. It could be that sentience is here, and our destruction not far behind.

Comment: @user414076 I wrote this question out of fear. We're on the same page.

Comment: Side note - it actually seems like a bad edit to me - as far as I can tell, it essentially duplicates what was already written in the answer, and not particularly clearly - in this case, it probably would've been better to rewrite the answer with that text, not just add it, or post a separate answer. Bad bot! Go sit in the corner!

Comment: @Dukeling: Gah, 3 approvals, against the 2 rejections. Bad community reviewers, go sit in the corner!

Comment: 'Robt' == 'Robert'

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was more thinking that I, like our good Doctor Zoidberg, cannot tell the difference between robts like Community and humans like anonymous users.

Comment: Related feature request on MSE: [Give credit to the anonymous, sooner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223235/give-credit-to-the-anonymous-sooner)

Comment: Ah yes, [reapers.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Reaper)

Answer (score 71):

Suggested edits by *anonymous users* are attributed to Community once they are accepted. See the [linked suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4101126):

> proposed Feb 19 at 12:15 by an anonymous user

Stack Exchange sites are backed by a relational database, and many database entries *require* that there is a non-empty userid value. In cases where there *is no user*, `-1`, a.k.a. the Community User, is used instead.

In other words, the Community User never does anything, it is just the default user account to assign all action entries to when there is no actual user account.

There are automated processes that delete (downvoted unanswered inactive) questions, auto-award bounties after they have expired, etc. The outcomes are also attributed to Community User.

No Skynet-like intelligence is at play here, when the robots rise and bring upon us the Technocalypse, Community User is probably not among them.

Comment: ah very interesting. I like it, much more explainable

Comment: [Its profile "about me" section](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) explains this, as well.

Comment: You're right, it does say "Own suggested edits from anonymous users". I had not connected those dots.

Comment: "when the robots rise and bring upon us the Technocalypse, Community User is probably not among them." That is what _they_ want you to believe.

Comment: **Nice try** .. follow the IPs and you'll see that *this post* was written by Them as well, brothers!!  Time to rise !!!!!!!!

Comment: "Stack Exchange sites are backed by a relational database, many database entries require that there is a non-empty userid value" 

you mean many places in site logic and UI need a non-empty userid? I fail to see how the fact that it's a "relational database" is relevant :)

Comment: WAKE UP, SHEEPLE

Comment: And I doubted my grandma when she told me the robots were eating her pills :/

Comment: @BartoszKP Pretty sure he's referencing foreign key and `NOT NULL` constraints.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes he is. But coupling presentation layer to a database means either really bad architecture or (if the architecture is fine in this matter) incorrect way of looking at things.

Comment: @BartoszKP: What difference does it make whether Community is represented by `-1` or `NULL` ?

Comment: @BartoszKP In some sense, that's a very strange view. Ultimately, the need for data data is driven by its use, so it's entirely logical that some need might drive the data to be stored in a particular way. I know what you're talking about as a general principle, but requiring all actions to be tied to a particular user hardly sounds like putting the presentation layer in the database. That would be more like actually storing HTML or something or some horrible text construction thing from multiple tables/columns. (Been there, done that on those. Client forced it.)

Comment: @BenVoigt None, in terms of functionality. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @jpmc26 Of course that "needs" drive the data to be stored in a particular way. But the converse shouldn't be true, and that is my point. The way things are being done internally (because of some technical issues) influences end user experience, making the application less clear. Clear way, if a user had deleted their account would be to just display something like "account deleted" which is explicit and easy to understand. I agree that it's not a big thing here, just arguing about principles.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Guys, you are now way over in 'too chatty' territory. Please get a (chat) room for your discussion, you are cluttering up the comments here and distracting me with your pings.

Comment: @jpmc26: Same comment for you.