# What would Community's rep (and badges) be, if it wasn't locked at 1 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-user

After reading the answer [Fantastic edit by Community user. Did it really do this?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258055/fantastic-edit-by-community-user-did-it-really-do-this?cb=1)

I was wondering if anyone has or is able to actually calculated what the Community users reputation should be (if it actually earned reputation from what anonymous users have contributed)? Also calculate the badges community has earned.

It would be interesting to see how much rep was lost by anonymous users.

And the most important question: Would this reputation/badge count be greater than Jon Skeet?

Comment: Even if it did earn reputation from those suggested edits, it would cap out on those +2 reputation increments at 1,000 reputation, like any other user. That's nowhere near Jon Skeet. Also, you can only earn a few single-award badges from editing things.

Comment: @animuson Aren't also dissociated posts attributed to community? In addition, does community get credit for auto-flags, which would make it an avid flagger?

Comment: @Deduplicator No, disassociated posts just plain don't have a user associated with them. The Community user "owns" (if you consider it ownership) community wiki posts, but those don't gain users reputation anyways. And even with the few badges for flagging and voting, that's still nothing compared to Jon Skeet.

Comment: Rep should be 42 for Community. Not sure if you got the question about Community's rep right though...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup><sub>{/serious}</sub></sup>

Community has been a bad person.  Very bad.  There have delete wars with mods in the past ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194496/why-is-the-community-user-in-a-close-war-with-a-mod)) and its necessary to keep Community down lest he (or she) try to close vote and delete the entire site.  Its true...

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't answer the question. The OP asked what Community's rep *would be* if it were not locked to 1 rep, not *why* it is locked to 1 rep. As it is, this post is at most a comment.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is Community's Reputation 1?

Very simple. It doesn't want to insult Jon Skeet.

> And the most important question: Would this reputation/badge count be greater than Jon Skeet?

Never. Jon Skeet would write a program to prevent his insult.

Comment: LOL! But not technically an answer - the question remains how much rep has been lost by anonymous users, and gone to Community instead.