# What does it mean when Community user approves an (incorrect) edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, community-user

[This incorrect edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5194699) to my post was suggested. It was rejected by two users, and approved by two users, one of them being the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user. The idea behind the edit was good though, and thanks to the fifth user who chose to improve the edit (thanks [Ritch Melton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402547/ritch-melton)!) all ended well, improving the post.

But I'm interested in how is it possible for the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user to approve suggested edits? :o

I'm guessing that it's not the case that some user approved an edit and after 3 hours deleted their account.

My next guess is that it could be some kind of SO business-logic-hack to automatically approve edits that get improved? If this is true, why present this fact in the UI? The information that some user chose the "Edit" option is clear enough whereas the information about Community user approval is misleading (it makes hard to see instantly what the approval/rejection ratio was for example).

Comment: Community auto approves when anyone improves an edit and doesn't untick the "this edit was helpful" box.

Comment: Related: [Why did the Community user reject my suggested edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250129) and [Fantastic edit by Community user. Did it really do this?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258055)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Community user approved the edit *on behalf of another user*. When a user improves a suggested edit, their action gets recorded as an **Edit** action, but then the suggested edit itself needs to be immediately approved or rejected since they are making a new edit on top of it. So that user is given the option to mark the edit as helpful or unhelpful, which then causes the Community user to approve or reject it respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :-) This seems to fit my last guess - don't you think that this might be misleading?

Comment: Maybe a little. But there's also not really an alternative. The user who performs that approve or reject *has* to be a moderator so that it will finish out the review no matter how many actions have been made prior. The Suggested Edits queue isn't like other queues. We can't just let the Edit action complete review because a suggested edit needs a solid approve or reject outcome. The Community user in general is confusing to anyone who doesn't understand what it is and how it works - that's just the nature of the beast.

Comment: Why not? The "edit" action seems to me as a form of approval (i.e. suggested edit was good enough to improve it). And this way or another, regardless of technical concerns, the UI shouldn't reflect such hacks. And yes, I know this is a very minor issue ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP: Actually, maybe it only led the reviewer to a post where he felt the unsurmountable urge to proffer some editing love. Whether the suggested edit was atrocious or brilliant.