# Should you give someone suggestions IN your edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

In [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7283024) a user added a comment into the asker's code, giving them a suggestion. Then the user actually changed a value, in line with this suggestion.

It looks like this could have been better as a comment, because it looks like the asker is just talking to himself.

Is this okay? It seemed to have been deemed acceptable by the people that approved it. Should I be doing this, too?

Comment: I feel that should have been either a comment or an answer, this method of answering a question doesn't give much to those who stumble on the question later.

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262181/what-does-it-mean-when-community-user-approves-an-incorrect-edit) but the answer is no, this is not the way to answer, comment, or use edits. No, you should not be doing this.

Comment: These edits are why we have the "attempt to reply" rejection reason.

Comment: That's not what the "suggested" part in "suggested edits" means.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### It is not a legitimate use of a suggested edit and it should not have been approved.

I've rolled it back and notified the editor.

As already noted, the reviewers should have rejected it, using this reason:

[image: attempt to reply]

If the review is particularly wrong, a moderator can be notified. Put a flag on the question or answer, select "other", explain the situation and include a link to the review.

Comment: Side note: Mods have the ability to ban reviewers if they're making many such poor decisions.